# Checking if part of the string is present in the database column

Tags: php, html, mysql

1. I have a text box to enter address
2. I have a table called `ward_master` in the `database`. It has a column named `ward_area` which has many area names separated by `comma` and `ward_name`.

On entering address, I need to check if the address contains the `ward_area`.

**Eg**: address: " FB cottage, 3rd cross, cordel road, Mumbai".

**DB**:

```
ward_name             ward_area
====================================================

MG Road              cordel road, Pvr cinema

Dongri               Frezzer town,sea side
```

This is my code for entering address :

```
<td><br>Address of Patient</td>
<td> <br> <input type="text" name="inc_patientAddress" id="wgtmsr" required</td>
```

How Can I check if the address consists a part of ward_area ?

Comment: try with LIKE '%%' query

Comment: are you mentioning  3rd cross as ward area ?

Comment: No cordel road as ward_area @krishna

Answer (score 0):

You might consider indexing your column with `FULL TEXT`. Full text indexing helps in such kind of search. [Read this  for more details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html)

Also the link here is for MySQL.

If you have  a different database please cross-reference.

Wild card `LIKE  % %`search won't work in your case as you wish to search only parts of the text not the whole and wild card does match the whole string

Comment: Can u please give an example of using indexing with full text

Comment: you just need to google @LillyShk First you need to change your table structure and add a full text index and then start firing your query for seach. There are already a lot of such examples.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), and count it to check existence. For Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ward_master WHERE FIND_IN_SET('yourvalue', ward_area);
```

Comment: its working when I give one word , But 'yourvalue' contains full address in which any one word might match the ward_area

Comment: You can split address "FB cottage, 3rd cross, cordel road, Mumbai", and check for match

Comment: if I split it say use' yourvalue'  as cordel once and  ' yourvalue'  as road the next time it will give all the ward names with ward_area "road"